# css/html: getting background-image path correct, for localhost

Tags: html, css

I'm using a web development program (Aptana) that when I run the html page, it runs it here:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/RadiantOrigins/index.html
```

Now, I have in my index.html file, style/css at the top in the head element:

```
body {
    /* background-color: red; */
    background-image: url('../EverythingImportant.jpg');
}
```

Ok, thanks, I can put the image under the same directory as the index.html file, and it finds it.

But if I put EverythingImportant.jpg under the images directory, a subdirectory where the project is, none of these work:

```
background-image: url('images/EverythingImportant.jpg');
background-image: url('/images/EverythingImportant.jpg');
background-image: url('./images/EverythingImportant.jpg');
background-image: url('../images/EverythingImportant.jpg');
```

Hmm, double checking.  Yup, none worked.

Comment: image paths in css are relative to the .css file location

Comment: you have a closing bracket for your body rule, don't you? (it's not there...) And not "background-re[eat", but "background-repeat"?

Comment: I do have closing, yes

Comment: If I bring the html file up where it is located on disk, using C:/... it works

Comment: Just not sure why it doesn't work with localhost

Comment: do you use "localhost" or the IP address to open the page?

Comment: maybe something with case sensitivity? (EverythingImportant.jpg / EverythingImportant.JPG / everythingimportant.jpg ...)

Comment: Sorry, not localhost, just as it is above

Comment: do you actually _see_ both these files (html and jpg) next to each other in the same directory on your file system?

Comment: Great question.  No.  The html file is in:  C:/radiant origins/website/code.  Hmm, and I have a space in radiant origins.  So I wonder where the Aptana program is running it?

Comment: RadiantOrigins is the Aptana project name

Comment: So I don't know where Aptana is running things ...

Comment: well, search the file system for "RadiantOrigins"... getting closer...

Comment: If I do: background-image: url('../images/EverythingImportant.jpg');  it doesn't work

Comment: I have an images directory "underneath" the index.html file

Comment: well, try  `background-image:  url('images/EverythingImportant.jpg');`

Comment: I did that too, does not work

Comment: Ok it finally works, thought I tried this before, as Sivadass is saying, to do: background-image: url('../EverythingImportant.jpg');

Comment: my last try: how about `background-image: url('/images/EverythingImportant.jpg');

Comment: aha, so it's one level higher - rather unusual...

Comment: yeah, so why can't I put it in the images subdirectory, let me try a few

Comment: Ok, so weird, please see updated question at the top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aptana doesn't see the image until you refresh it's file contents inside the tool.  So even though you have the image there, it doesn't recognize it.

Answer (score 2):

try it as...

```
background-image: url('../EverythingImportant.jpg');
```

Comment: My styles are inline in the document, at the top

Comment: just enter the image url in the browser and check whether url is working http://127.0.0.1:8000/RadiantOrigins/EverythingImportant.jpg

Comment: If I do that, it says it is not found

Comment: URL may be wrong then, double check the file name of the image and Parent folder

Comment: Thanks, good feedback, please see comments under question